# PHP-showing weird entries when retrieved from database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have written this PHP code but it is giving some weird result. The snippet is

```
$queryIsbnArr = mysql_query("select ISBN from quotation_master") or die(mysql_error());
            $row = mysql_fetch_array($queryIsbnArr) or die(mysql_error()); 
            print_r($row);
            $_SESSION['isbnArr'] = $row;
```

The output which the query is giving is..

```
Array ( [0] => 12121 [ISBN] => 12121 )
```

Where as the output which is query is giving when run on the database is

```
12121
56
```

Which is correct.What is the problem with this then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)!

> Returns an array of strings that corresponds to the fetched row, or FALSE if there are no more rows. The type of returned array depends on how result_type is defined. **By using MYSQL_BOTH (default), you'll get an array with both associative and number indices.**

`mysql_fetch_array()` fetches both a numerical and associative array of each row's data. You need to use or the other to get the actual data as `$row` contains the entire dataset as an array even if it is only one value.

```
$queryIsbnArr = mysql_query("select ISBN from quotation_master") or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryIsbnArr) or die(mysql_error()); 
print_r($row['ISBN']);
$_SESSION['isbnArr'] = $row;
```

FYI, [you shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly fine, when you use [`mysql_fetch_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) it will get you value in both places, by index and column name

and for multiple rows you have to loop through like:-

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($queryIsbnArr)){
    print_r($row);
}
```